# ASP.NET IConfigurationSection is returning null objects for POCO

Tags: asp.net, json, appsettings

I looked through various solutions posted on StackOverflow -- many were outdated.
The intent is to use IConfigurationSection.Get to return a POCO object from a json section via JsonConfigurationExtensions.

The simplest case:

```
IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
IConfiguration configuration = builder.Build();
return configuration.GetSection("ServerConfiguration").Get<ServerConfiguration>();
```

And a nested POCO:

```
public class ServerConfiguration
{
    public Authentication Authentication { get; internal set; }
}

public class Authentication
{
   public DatabaseConfiguration UserDatabase { get; internal set; }
}

public class DatabaseConfiguration
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; internal set; }

    public string DatabaseName { get; internal set; }
}
```

The result is a null object.

In order to "clean up" my code at inception, I actually did not include the set property declarations as it wasn't needed in previous Json to POCO handlers.  However, even when declaring these handlers (typically non-public) the ASP.NET implementation for Json file processing was always returning null although retrieving the individual key pairs from the section was successful.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was buried in a response in the ASP.NET forum: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/issues/394#issuecomment-444683884

The resulting change in the code:

1) Make sure there is a declaration of a set handler (internal, protected, private).
2) Specify BindOptions => BindNonPublicProperties.

```
return configuration.GetSection("ServerConfiguration")
           .Get<ServerConfiguration>(c => c.BindNonPublicProperties = true);
```